# check and uncheck checkboxes individually despite of have been created in for loop in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Good Day Developers, 
I just have created an array of checkboxes and wnat to check-uncheck each one separatedly , but when i trigger te action , all of then check or uncheck at same time , here what i ave done:

```
HTML

                        <v-layout v-for="(option,index) in ProductAdded.Categories" :key="index">
                          <v-flex xs12>
                            <div>
                              <input
                                name="id of product"
                                label="id of product"
                                v-model="option.value"
                                type="checkbox"
                                checked
                                @click="option.selected = !option.selected"

                              />
                              <label>{{ option.value }}</label>
                            </div>
                          </v-flex>
                        </v-layout>
```

In the script then inside the data for each Object inside the array of ProductAdded.Categories i just created an item called selected, being then triggered to true or false attuning with the @click previosly set in the HTML tag:

```
SCRIPT

data() {
    return {

      ProductAdded: {
        description: "",
        upload_image3: "",
        upload_image2: "",
        upload_image1: "",
        unities: 0,
        price: 0,
        name: "",
        Categories: [
          { id: 1, value: "Miscellaneous", selected: true },
          { id: 2, value: "Homer", selected: true },
          { id: 3, value: "Electronic", selected: true },
          { id: 4, value: "Internet", selected: true },
          { id: 5, value: "Kids", selected: true },
          { id: 6, value: "Donas", selected: true },
          { id: 7, value: "Sports", selected: true },
          { id: 8, value: "Horror", selected: true }
        ]
      },

    };
```

But guess this isn't properly set cause on check-uncheck the action triggers all checkboxes instead of only the one i click on.
Any advice about what i should do?
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: based on the click you have to change the data , that way your checkboxes will be checked and unchecked appropriately

Comment: could you explain please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot model a string attribute with a checkbox. Checkboxes are modeling boolean values only.

The code runs fine without `v-model="option.value"`:

```js
var vue = new Vue({
  el: '#vue',
  data: {
      ProductAdded: {
        description: "",
        upload_image3: "",
        upload_image2: "",
        upload_image1: "",
        unities: 0,
        price: 0,
        name: "",
        Categories: [
          { id: 1, value: "Miscellaneous", selected: true },
          { id: 2, value: "Homer", selected: true },
          { id: 3, value: "Electronic", selected: true },
          { id: 4, value: "Internet", selected: true },
          { id: 5, value: "Kids", selected: true },
          { id: 6, value: "Donas", selected: true },
          { id: 7, value: "Sports", selected: true },
          { id: 8, value: "Horror", selected: true }
        ]
      }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="vue">
  <div v-for="(option,index) in ProductAdded.Categories" :key="index">
     <input
        name="id of product"
        label="id of product"
        type="checkbox"
        checked
        @click="option.selected = !option.selected"
      />
      <label>{{ option.value }}</label>
  </div>
  <pre>Data:<br />{{JSON.stringify(ProductAdded.Categories, null, '  ')}}</pre>
</div>
```